# Percentage of a color in OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv

I making a function that extract the RGB Channels from an image to calculate the average color of a picture.

I want the result like this:

Image A : Red layer: 25%, Green layer: 40%, Blue layer: 35%.

Im using Opencv in Android, and have a function that can split the layers, but, how to calculate???

```
Mat mRgb = m;
    List<Mat> lRgb = new ArrayList<Mat>(3);

    List<Mat> red = new ArrayList<Mat>(3);
    List<Mat> green = new ArrayList<Mat>(3);
    List<Mat> blue = new ArrayList<Mat>(3);

    Mat mRed = new Mat();
    Mat mGreen = new Mat();
    Mat mBlue = new Mat();

    //Split the RGB channels

    Core.split(mRgb, lRgb);

    //Apply Mat 

    Mat mR = lRgb.get(0);
    Mat mG = Mat.zeros(m.rows(), m.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    Mat mB = Mat.zeros(m.rows(), m.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1);


    red.add(mR);
    red.add(mG);
    red.add(mB);

    Core.merge(red, mRed); // Return return red matrix

    //Apply Mat 
    mR = Mat.zeros(m.rows(), m.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    mG = lRgb.get(1);
    mB = Mat.zeros(m.rows(), m.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1);

    green.add(mR);
    green.add(mG);
    green.add(mB);

    Core.merge(green, mGreen); //Return green matrix

    //Apply Mat 
    mR = Mat.zeros(m.rows(), m.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    mG = Mat.zeros(m.rows(), m.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    mB = lRgb.get(2);

    blue.add(mR);
    blue.add(mG);
    blue.add(mB);

    Core.merge(blue, mBlue); //Return blue matrix
```

Can you help me with these?

Comment: By layer do you mean a color channel?

Comment: Thats it! Color channel.. Sorry if i'm not making myself clear.

Comment: I dont understand what you want to compute... can you give a small example image and and approximate result from intuition?

Comment: for example, if the whole image has r=255 and g=b=0, the result is 100% red? same if r=50 and b=g=0? what if each pixel has r=200,g=100,b=50? would the last example have the same result if half of the pixels are black (r=g=b=0)?

Comment: Exactly this, i almost getting this to work, the only problem, is to get the mean values from each channel...

Comment: use opencv's mean function on the color image. http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#Scalar mean(InputArray src, InputArray mask) return value is a scalar with 3 values, each one is the mean of a single channel